# Mask out specific values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, membership

Example:

I have an array:

```
array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 4, 2, 1, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1],
       [4, 2, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

I have a set (variable length, order doesn't matter) of "bad" values:

```
{2, 3}
```

I want to return the mask that hides these values:

```
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

What's the simplest way to do this in NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) that gives us a flattened mask of such matching occurrences and then reshape back to input array shape for the desired output, like so -

```
np.in1d(a,[2,3]).reshape(a.shape)
```

Note that we need to feed in the numbers to be searched as a list or an array.

Sample run -

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 4, 2, 1, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1],
       [4, 2, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]])

In [6]: np.in1d(a,[2,3]).reshape(a.shape)
Out[6]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

#### 2018 Edition : `numpy.isin`

Use NumPy built-in [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) (introduced in [`1.13.0`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.13.0-notes.rst#new-functions)) that keeps the shape and hence doesn't require us to reshape afterwards -

```
In [153]: np.isin(a,[2,3])
Out[153]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [965]: np.any([x==i for i in (2,3)],axis=0)
Out[965]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

This does iterate, but if the `(2,3)` set is small (relative to the size of `x`) this is relatively fast.  In fact for small `arr2`, `np.in1d` does this:

```
        mask = np.zeros(len(ar1), dtype=np.bool)
        for a in ar2:
            mask |= (ar1 == a)
```

Making a masked array from this:

```
In [970]: np.ma.MaskedArray(x,mask)
Out[970]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 -- 0 -- 4]
 [0 4 -- 1 --]
 [4 -- -- 0 1]
 [4 -- -- 0 1]
 [1 0 -- -- 4]
 [4 -- -- 0 1]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False  True False]
 [False False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [False False  True  True False]
 [False  True  True False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: That `[x==i for i in (2,3)]` would occupy `N` times more memory than the final output, N being the number of elems in search array. Askers post sample, which doesn't necessarily they are dealing with those exact small inputs, specially when they are looking for performance.

Comment: `in1d`'s loop equivalent saves that larger memory use. Speeds probably the same. But we'd have to test.  It may not be the optimal solution for all cases, but I think it's a good basic solution.

Comment: Yeah there would be function wrapper overhead with `np.in1d`, but mostly comparable performance I would think.

Answer (score 1):

There might be simpler ways than this. But this can be one way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 4, 2, 1, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1],
       [4, 2, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]], dtype=np.int64)

f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x in {2,3})
print f(a)
```

Output:

```
[[False  True False  True False]
 [False False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [False False  True  True False]
 [False  True  True False False]]
```

Comment: `vectorize` is just a `for` loop though, isn't it?