# drop all rows after first occurance of NaN in specific column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am trying to use the dropna function in pandas. I would like to use it for a specific column.

I can only figure out how to use it to drop NaN if ALL rows have ALL NaN values.

I have a dataframe (see below) that I would like to drop all rows after the first occurance of an NaN in a **specific** column, column "A"

current code, only works if all row values are NaN.

```
data.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
data
```

Original Dataframe

```
    data = pd.DataFrame({"A": (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"NaN","NaN","NaN"),"B": (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"NaN","9","10"),"C": range(10)})
    data


    A   B   C
0   1   1   0
1   2   2   1
2   3   3   2
3   4   4   3
4   5   5   4
5   6   6   5
6   7   7   6
7   NaN NaN 7
8   NaN 9   8
9   NaN 10  9
```

What I would like the output to look like:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   0
1   2   2   1
2   3   3   2
3   4   4   3
4   5   5   4
5   6   6   5
6   7   7   6
```

Any help on this is appreciated.
Obviously I am would like to do it in the cleanest most efficient way possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `iloc` + `argmax`

```
data.iloc[:data.A.isnull().values.argmax()]

     A  B  C
0  1.0  1  0
1  2.0  2  1
2  3.0  3  2
3  4.0  4  3
4  5.0  5  4
5  6.0  6  5
6  7.0  7  6
```

or with a different syntax

```
top_data = data[:data['A'].isnull().argmax()]
```

Comment: @MaxU almost, that depends on the index being nicely ordered ints.  I fixed it another way.

Comment: can you go any faster here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318942/mask-out-specific-values-from-an-array

Comment: What was wrong with loc + idxmax? Also I think you don't need `.values`, `Series` also has `argmax` method.

Comment: `loc` takes both end points.  `idxmax` returned index where `nan` first happened and was included in results with `loc`.  MaxU first suggested using `+1` but that doesn't generalize if the index were not conveniently ordered integers.  `iloc` excludes the end point, but now i have to find the position and not the index.  So I had to use `argmax`.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared yes, it works perfectly so far. And yes in my actual working dataframe it is a mix of integers and strings (I should have put some strings in the example).

Answer (score 2):

Re: accepted answer. If column in question has no NaNs, argmax returns 0 and thus df[:argmax] will return an empty dataframe.

Here's my workaround:

```
max_ = data.A.isnull().argmax()  
max_ = len(data) if max_ == 0 else max_
top_data = data[:max_]
```