# Why dropna() is dropping extra rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all rows that have atleast one 'NaN'. The dataframe looks like below but the actual one has around 1000004 rows.

The full CSV file: [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CUcBRWDWUSQOOSvDOH-gZ7UFgl-U31DU/view?usp=sharing)

| Time (µs) | ChannelA (mV) | ChannelB (mV) | ChannelC (mV) | ChannelD (mV) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.5 | NaN | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.6 | NaN | 0.3 | 0.11 |
| 4 | 0.8 | 0.6 | NaN | 0.6 |
| 5 | 0.7 | 0.1 | 0.4 | NaN |

The code I have written is as follows:

```
def fft(x, Plot_ShareY=True):

    #loads the csv files 
    dfs = pd.read_csv(x, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1,2), decimal=",", na_values='NaN')
 
    #removes spaces in column names   
    dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs)  
    dfs.columns = dfs.columns.str.replace(' ', '') #removes spaces from col names
    
    #removes infinity symbol and converts non-numeric values to NaN
    for c in dfs:
        dfs[c] = pd.to_numeric(dfs[c], errors='coerce') 
    
    #drops NaN
    dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
    print(dfs)
```

I expect to have atleast 300000 rows but I get only around 200000 rows. When I check in the actual CSV file, the first NaN does not occur atleast until the 380000 th row. So why is `dropna()` removing extra rows ?

Comment: Have you checked a sample of the dataframe to see if you can spot a row that should have been dropped and wasn't? Have you checked that the infinity removal actually works?

Comment: I checked with the datatype and all the datatypes are float64, so that way I know that no non-numeric values exist. The infinity removal also works and I check that with the data type as well. But one problem here is that python still warns me that a mixed data type exists even when everything is float 64!

Comment: What you say must be wrong. Check the dataframe just after converting all columns to numeric. You are probably creating more nan values than you think

Comment: @lqope54 then can you provide the full dataset?

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu I checked according to what you said. It is not creating extra NaN values but it is actually converting numeric values to NaN. And they are not very small (are -1.8 and -1.09)

Comment: can you try ```dfs[c].astype(float)``` instead of ```pd.to_numeric(dfs[c], errors='coerce')```

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu Got this error: `could not convert string to float: '150,16480000'`. I previously tried specifying dtype when importing but that also did not work. It was the same code but just dtype specified in pd.read_csv

Comment: This is your problem. For some values you have comma as a separator and for some you have dot as separator

Comment: When the values become some hundered thounsand, then a comma is inserted after the third place value. But for the first 380000 rows, this is not a problem and I am interested in these few rows.

Comment: then also you can just do this  ```dfs = dfs.loc[0:380_000].copy()```  and also use ```dfs[c].astype(float)``` for conversion

Comment: what is infinity symbol you mean `-∞` ?

Comment: @KarnKumar yes. When I open the CSV file on notepad I see the infinity symbol for non-numeric values.

Comment: @lqope54, do you want all `-∞` to be replaced by `Nan`  as well or what you want for them?

Comment: I do not want any of those non-numeric symbols.

Comment: I understand, but then you want those to be null or `Nan` ?

Comment: Null as in would be 0 (become a numeric value) ? If it becomes a numeric value then no. It would be suitable to convert it to NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the different approach as I see using `pd.to_numeric(dfs[c], errors='coerce')` making it all `Nan` in my testing and returning empty DataFrame while applying `dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')`, So, best bet it to replace symbols(`∞ & -∞`) to `np.nan` and then remove `Nan` rows.

While trimming all the Whitespace, better use `strip`  to remove both ends space on all the columns.

### Solution:

You will be getting `387060` rows.

```
dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", delimiter=";", skiprows=(1,2), decimal=",", na_values=['(NA)'], low_memory=False)
dfs = dfs.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
dfs = dfs.replace({'-∞': np.nan, '∞': np.nan})
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
print(dfs)
```

### Results:

```
dfs.head()

        Time    Channel A    Channel B    Channel C    Channel D
0 -20.000096  -0,36625560  -1,09876700   0,00000000  -0,36625560
1 -20.000046  -0,36625560  -1,46502200  -0,36625560   0,30521300
2 -19.999996   0,30521300  -0,73251120   0,00000000  -0,36625560
3 -19.999946  -0,36625560  -1,09876700   0,00000000   0,00000000
4 -19.999896   0,67146860  -0,36625560   0,30521300   0,00000000

dfs.tail()
             Time      Channel A     Channel B      Channel C      Channel D
944234  27.211601  -358,74740000  499,81680000  -169,21010000  -236,17380000
944237  27.211751  -358,74740000  499,81680000  -169,57640000  -235,44130000
944239  27.211851  -358,74740000  499,81680000  -169,94260000  -235,80760000
944240  27.211901  -358,74740000  499,81680000  -170,30890000  -235,80760000
944241  27.211951  -359,11360000  499,81680000  -170,30890000  -236,17380000
```

Comment: Ok, two questions though. Why is the df not converting to point based decimal system. And what is the line with 'lambda' doing ?

Comment: @lqope54, I just updated my answer, this is not something you want? Then may be i misunderstood your question.

Comment: The number of rows are fine and makes sense when I compare with the actual CSV file. But if you see the 'Time' column the values are separated by decimal and in the other columns it is separated with a comma. I would like to convert them all to decimal.

Comment: @lqope54, see the updated answer, hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I was wondering if instead of doing so much, I could simply delete all rows after the first instance of NaN in any column. I tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320406/drop-all-rows-after-first-occurance-of-nan-in-specific-column-pandas) but I always get an empty array !

Comment: Okay, Doesn't these 3 lines code works for you, this way optimized and simplified.

`dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", skiprows=(0,1,2), sep=',',names=['Numbers','Time','Channel A','Channel B','Channel C','Channel D'], dtype='unicode')
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
dfs = dfs.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0])`

Comment: They remove the rows from the middle and then combine the first few and last few rows which don't have NaN and because of the difference in values, the further processings that I do creates a graph with sharp differences. So I thought of removing all the rows when the first NaN occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236085/discussion-between-lqope54-and-karn-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

You have improper cell values. You have to clean your data before converting it to numeric

```
dfs = dfs.loc[0:380_000].copy()
for c in dfs:
    dfs[c] = dfs[c].astype(float)

#drops NaN
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
print(dfs)
```

Comment: Gives an error: `Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: changed the code to convert everything to str. Can you try again?

Comment: This would not work as it would convert 35 thousand (35,000) to 35 (35.000). And these higher values are not important any way. Only interested in the first 380000 or so rows.

Comment: filter for the first 380000 rows and do the type conversion on them. If you still have errors simply fix those rows

Comment: That would be the simplest thing to do but since I have a picture of the response from the experiment, I know that I need the first 380000 rows. But if not, I wouldn't know. And every file will have a different number of rows that I need.

Comment: Then you should find a way to clean the data. Maybe the minus sign is causing the problem. You can try replacing that also.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Code:

you can use `stack` and `unstack` with vectorised `str.replace` to convert `,` to `.` and you are done:

```
dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", delimiter=";", skiprows=(1,2), decimal=",", na_values=['(NA)'], low_memory=False)
dfs = dfs.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
dfs = dfs.replace({'-∞': np.nan, '∞': np.nan})
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')

dfs = dfs[['Channel A', 'Channel B', 'Channel C', 'Channel D']].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
#dfs = dfs[['Channel A', 'Channel B', 'Channel C', 'Channel D']].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack().astype(float)   <-- this change the datatype to float
```

Or Just to be a little more handy, you can difine the column names the run the replace function.

```
cols = ['Channel A', 'Channel B', 'Channel C', 'Channel D']
dfs = dfs[cols].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

OR

```
dfs = dfs.loc[:, dfs.columns != 'Time'].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

OR

```
dfs = dfs[dfs.columns.difference(['Time'])].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

OR

```
dfs = dfs.loc[:, ~dfs.columns.isin(['Time'])].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

OR

```
dfs = dfs[dfs.columns.drop('Time')].stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

OR

```
dfs = dfs.drop('Time', axis=1).stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
# dfs = dfs.drop(columns='Time').stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

### result:

dfs.head()

```
        Time  Channel A  Channel B  Channel C  Channel D
0 -20.000096  -0.366256  -1.098767   0.000000  -0.366256
1 -20.000046  -0.366256  -1.465022  -0.366256   0.305213
2 -19.999996   0.305213  -0.732511   0.000000  -0.366256
3 -19.999946  -0.366256  -1.098767   0.000000   0.000000
4 -19.999896   0.671469  -0.366256   0.305213   0.000000
```

dfs.tail()

```
             Time  Channel A  Channel B  Channel C  Channel D
944234  27.211601  -358.7474   499.8168  -169.2101  -236.1738
944237  27.211751  -358.7474   499.8168  -169.5764  -235.4413
944239  27.211851  -358.7474   499.8168  -169.9426  -235.8076
944240  27.211901  -358.7474   499.8168  -170.3089  -235.8076
944241  27.211951  -359.1136   499.8168  -170.3089  -236.1738
```

## Update

While thoroughly reading of your csv file and looking at the data, this needs cleaning at the onset itself..

You literally have 5 columns underneath on the excel file `(ms);(mV);(mV);(mV);(mV)` for some kind of conductivity measures? ...

[image]

### new code will be:

```
dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", skiprows=(0,1,2), sep=',',names=['Numbers','Time','Channel A','Channel B','Channel C','Channel D'], dtype='unicode')
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
print(dfs.head(200))
```

### results with modified solution:

```
       Numbers           Time      Channel A      Channel B      Channel C Channel D
0          -20    00009598;-0    36625560;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
1          -20    00004598;-0    36625560;-1    46502200;-0     36625560;0  30521300
2          -19     99999598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0    00000000;-0  36625560
3          -19    99994598;-0    36625560;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  00000000
4          -19     99989598;0    67146860;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  00000000
5          -19    99984598;-0    73251120;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
6          -19     99979598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
7          -19    99974598;-0    36625560;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
8          -19     99969598;0    00000000;-1    09876700;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
9          -19    99964598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
10         -19    99959598;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
11         -19     99954598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
12         -19     99949598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  30521300
13         -19     99944598;0    30521300;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  30521300
14         -19     99939598;0    00000000;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  00000000
15         -19     99934598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
16         -19     99929598;0    00000000;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
17         -19     99924598;0    30521300;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
18         -19     99919598;0    30521300;-0    73251120;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
19         -19     99914598;0    00000000;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  30521300
20         -19     99909598;0    30521300;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  30521300
21         -19    99904598;-0    36625560;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  00000000
22         -19     99899598;0    00000000;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  00000000
23         -19    99894598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  67146860
24         -19    99889598;-0    73251120;-1     46502200;0    00000000;-0  36625560
25         -19     99884598;0    30521300;-1    09876700;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
26         -19     99879598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  30521300
27         -19     99874598;0    00000000;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
28         -19     99869598;0    30521300;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
29         -19     99864598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
30         -19    99859598;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  00000000
31         -19    99854598;-0    36625560;-1    09876700;-0     36625560;0  00000000
32         -19     99849598;0    67146860;-1    09876700;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
33         -19     99844598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     30521300;0  67146860
34         -19     99839598;0    67146860;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  30521300
35         -19     99834598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  00000000
36         -19     99829598;0    00000000;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  00000000
37         -19     99824598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-1     09876700;0  00000000
38         -19     99819598;0    30521300;-1    09876700;-0    36625560;-0  73251120
39         -19    99814598;-0    73251120;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  00000000
40         -19    99809598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
41         -19     99804598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0    36625560;-0  36625560
42         -19    99799598;-0    36625560;-1    09876700;-0     36625560;0  00000000
43         -19     99794598;0    30521300;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  00000000
44         -19     99789598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
45         -19    99784598;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0     73251120;0  30521300
46         -19     99779598;0    00000000;-1    09876700;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
47         -19     99774598;0    30521300;-1     46502200;0    67146860;-0  73251120
48         -19     99769598;0    00000000;-0     36625560;0    00000000;-0  36625560
49         -19     99764598;0    30521300;-1     09876700;0     00000000;0  00000000
50         -19     99759598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0    00000000;-0  36625560
51         -19     99754598;0    00000000;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  00000000
52         -19     99749598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     30521300;0  00000000
53         -19     99744598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
54         -19     99739598;0    30521300;-1    09876700;-0     36625560;0  00000000
55         -19     99734598;0    00000000;-1    09876700;-0     36625560;0  00000000
56         -19     99729598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0     73251120;0  00000000
57         -19     99724598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  30521300
58         -19     99719598;0    30521300;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  30521300
59         -19     99714598;0    00000000;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  00000000
60         -19     99709598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
61         -19     99704598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
62         -19     99699598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0    00000000;-0  36625560
63         -19    99694598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
64         -19     99689598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
65         -19     99684598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  30521300
66         -19     99679598;0     30521300;0     00000000;0     30521300;0  00000000
67         -19    99674598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
68         -19     99669598;0    00000000;-1     46502200;0     00000000;0  00000000
69         -19     99664598;0    00000000;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  00000000
70         -19     99659598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
71         -19    99654598;-0    73251120;-1     46502200;0    00000000;-0  36625560
72         -19     99649598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
73         -19     99644598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0    30521300;-0  36625560
74         -19    99639598;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  30521300
75         -19    99634598;-0    36625560;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
76         -19     99629598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  67146860
77         -19     99624598;0    30521300;-1     46502200;0    00000000;-0  36625560
78         -19     99619598;0    30521300;-0    36625560;-0     73251120;0  30521300
79         -19     99614598;0    67146860;-1     09876700;0     30521300;0  67146860
80         -19    99609598;-0    36625560;-1    46502200;-0     36625560;0  00000000
81         -19     99604598;0    30521300;-0    73251120;-0     73251120;0  30521300
82         -19     99599598;0    30521300;-0     36625560;0     67146860;0  30521300
83         -19    99594598;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  00000000
84         -19     99589598;0    30521300;-0     36625560;0     30521300;0  00000000
85         -19     99584598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
86         -19     99579598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     30521300;0  00000000
87         -19     99574598;0    30521300;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  73251120
88         -19     99569598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
89         -19     99564598;0     00000000;0     00000000;0    00000000;-0  36625560
90         -19     99559598;0    30521300;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  73251120
91         -19     99554598;0    30521300;-0     36625560;0     00000000;0  67146860
92         -19     99549598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  30521300
93         -19    99544598;-0    36625560;-0    36625560;-0     36625560;0  00000000
94         -19     99539598;0    00000000;-0    73251120;-0    73251120;-0  36625560
95         -19    99534598;-0    36625560;-1     09876700;0    00000000;-0  36625560
96         -19    99529598;-0    36625560;-1    09876700;-0     36625560;0  00000000
97         -19     99524598;0    00000000;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  00000000
98         -19    99519598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0     36625560;0  00000000
99         -19     99514598;0    30521300;-0     73251120;0     00000000;0  30521300
100        -19    99509598;-0    36625560;-0    73251120;-0     73251120;0  00000000
```

------------------------ snipped --------------------------------

### Refined Solution:

In case want to get rid of anything after `;*` including `;`, then you can use below..

```
dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", skiprows=(0,1,2), sep=',',names=['Numbers','Time','Channel A','Channel B','Channel C','Channel D'], dtype='unicode')
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
dfs['Time'] = dfs['Time'].str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0]
dfs['Channel A'] = dfs['Channel A'].str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0]
dfs['Channel B'] = dfs['Channel B'].str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0]
dfs['Channel C'] = dfs['Channel C'].str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0]
dfs['Channel D'] = dfs['Channel D'].str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0]
# or in single lambda function
# dfs = dfs.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0])
```

**refind results:**

```
   Numbers      Time Channel A Channel B Channel C Channel D
0      -20  00009598  36625560  09876700  00000000  36625560
1      -20  00004598  36625560  46502200  36625560  30521300
2      -19  99999598  30521300  73251120  00000000  36625560
3      -19  99994598  36625560  09876700  00000000  00000000
4      -19  99989598  67146860  36625560  30521300  00000000
5      -19  99984598  73251120  73251120  00000000  00000000
6      -19  99979598  00000000  73251120  00000000  00000000
7      -19  99974598  36625560  09876700  00000000  36625560
8      -19  99969598  00000000  09876700  36625560  36625560
9      -19  99964598  36625560  73251120  36625560  36625560
10     -19  99959598  73251120  73251120  36625560  36625560
11     -19  99954598  30521300  73251120  00000000  00000000
12     -19  99949598  00000000  73251120  00000000  30521300
13     -19  99944598  30521300  36625560  30521300  30521300
14     -19  99939598  00000000  09876700  00000000  00000000
15     -19  99934598  30521300  73251120  00000000  00000000
16     -19  99929598  00000000  09876700  00000000  36625560
17     -19  99924598  30521300  09876700  00000000  36625560
18     -19  99919598  30521300  73251120  36625560  36625560
19     -19  99914598  00000000  36625560  30521300  30521300
20     -19  99909598  30521300  09876700  00000000  30521300
```

Just to show the simplified and extracted version tested on the given dataset:

Just clean the data as max during feed ...

### Solution:

```
dfs = pd.read_csv("Pipe03_2.csv", skiprows=(0,1,2), sep=',',names=['Numbers','Time','Channel A','Channel B','Channel C','Channel D'], dtype='unicode')
dfs = dfs.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
dfs = dfs.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(";", expand=True, n=1)[0])
```

### Result:

```
   Numbers      Time Channel A Channel B Channel C Channel D
0      -20  00009598  36625560  09876700  00000000  36625560
1      -20  00004598  36625560  46502200  36625560  30521300
2      -19  99999598  30521300  73251120  00000000  36625560
3      -19  99994598  36625560  09876700  00000000  00000000
4      -19  99989598  67146860  36625560  30521300  00000000
5      -19  99984598  73251120  73251120  00000000  00000000
6      -19  99979598  00000000  73251120  00000000  00000000
7      -19  99974598  36625560  09876700  00000000  36625560
8      -19  99969598  00000000  09876700  36625560  36625560
9      -19  99964598  36625560  73251120  36625560  36625560
10     -19  99959598  73251120  73251120  36625560  36625560
11     -19  99954598  30521300  73251120  00000000  00000000
12     -19  99949598  00000000  73251120  00000000  30521300
13     -19  99944598  30521300  36625560  30521300  30521300
14     -19  99939598  00000000  09876700  00000000  00000000
15     -19  99934598  30521300  73251120  00000000  00000000
16     -19  99929598  00000000  09876700  00000000  36625560
17     -19  99924598  30521300  09876700  00000000  36625560
18     -19  99919598  30521300  73251120  36625560  36625560
19     -19  99914598  00000000  36625560  30521300  30521300
20     -19  99909598  30521300  09876700  00000000  30521300
```